# How to label branches of a phylogenetic tree with specific mutations?

Tags: variant, phylogeny

I want to generate a phylogenetic tree of a bacterial population [MRSA] that can describe/annotate mutations per branch for that population. I was able to generate the phylogenetic tree but have not been able to assign specific mutations that could define each branch.
I came across a website called ‘NextClade’ that generates the exact graph we want but its only for viruses. I am trying to look for other tools that can generate the tree with required annotations for other species as well.

You can have a look at the tree by running an example in the site.
Nextclade website: https://clades.nextstrain.org/results

- You can click on run an example
- See the comparison graphs
- Click on upper right corner tree option.
- We can click on each individual branch and look at mutations leading to that branch.

Comment: Maybe ask this question in discussion.nextstrain.org